# How To Recreate A Table In Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I dropped a table manually in magento. Now I want my code to recreate the same table.. I Have written the create statement in `app/code/local/namespace/my_module/sql` folder like this

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('cod')};
CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('cod')} (
    `cod_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `status` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
    'amount' int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `created_time` datetime NULL,
    `update_time` datetime NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`cod_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

How will this query execute so that it can recreate the table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query is executed when you run magento with your module first time. After this magento adds row to core_resource table *my_module_setup | 0.01 | 0.01* 
which means, your module was set up successfully. 
So, to recreate table you should drop row *my_module_setup* from *core_resource* table and run any magento page again.
Please note, version & data_version columns let you hold module's version  up to date. If you change module's version in config.xml to higher than it is in *core_resource*, magento will look for *mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php*.